# How to Handle Button Clicks ListFragment

Tags: android-fragments, android

I was curious how best to handle button clicks, inside of a `ListFragment` with a custom adapter.

I have an `onClickListener` setup for the buttons, but I need to be able to get the item that it was clicked from, since it is within an item, here is the `getView` inside the custom adapter.

```
*/
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_single_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TestItemModel item = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_label)).setText(item.getName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_id)).setText(item.getId());
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        Resources resources = this.getContext().getResources();
        image.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        Button btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id_2);
        Button btn3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id_3);
        ol = new OnItemClickListener(position);
        btn.setOnClickListener(ol);
        btn.setTag(1);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(ol);
        btn2.setTag(2);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(ol);
        btn3.setTag(3);

        return view;
    }
```

as you can see I used tags to determine which button was clicked and the `OnItemClickListener` knows where the position is from the position at which is being called.

I am not sure about the best approach and how to go about doing this properly.

Comment: why not use a switch case in `onClick` ??

Comment: can't get the item that was clicked. and also need the position for the click to know which item it was clicked in.

Comment: you can i don't see a issue with it

Comment: provide an example of a click that would provide that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a switch case as below

```
private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.button_id :
                    // btn clicked
                            Toast.makeText(context," Button1 clicked at positon"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.button_id2 :
                    // btn2 clicked   
                           Toast.makeText(context," Button2 clicked at positon"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;  
                case R.id.button_id3 :
                            Toast.makeText(context," Button3 clicked at positon"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    // btn 3 clciked
                    break; 
                }

            }
        };
```

Use

```
btn.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
btn.setTag(position);
btn2.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
btn2.setTag(position);
btn3.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
btn3.setTag(position);
```

Snap of example with two buttons

snap of button 1 clicked at position 0 ie first row

[image]

snap of button 2 clicked at position 1 ie second row

[image]

Comment: Aside from providing what item that specifically is, that ultimately works, I figured out my issue.

I put this in there to fix my problem. 

ol = new OnItemClickListener(position, item);

added item to the OnItemClickListener I was using, my question to you is, does this prevent good model view separation? and are there repercussions here, because ultimately  database transaction will be performed on these button clicks, down the line

Comment: @kev2316 do try the above it will work and what was your issue which you din't mention in the question

Comment: Initially my question would have been how to pass the item associated with the button that was clicked to the listener to perform action on that, which I have solved, since your doing what I was doing sorry, but now my question to you is, whether or not this is efficient and following proper model view separation.

Comment: @kev2316 i don't see a problem with is approach