# get position of button in listfragment

Tags: java, android, button, fragment

I am using a fragment and cursoradapter to display incoming messages. For every message there is a button that can be clicked. My onclick is implemented in the underlying activity shown below.

```android
public class ChatActivity extends FragmentActivity implements StatFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ChatFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, EditContactDialog.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    profileId = getIntent().getStringExtra(Common.PROFILE_ID);
    //msgEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_edit);
    msgInvite_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgInvite_edit);
    buttonNewInvite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNewInvite);
    buttonYES = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ans1 = getIntent().getIntExtra(DataProvider.COL_ANSCOUNT, 0);
    //BAS: de zendknop voor het antwoorden op de Invite
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
    //checkBtn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    //buttonId = getIntent.getStringExtra(DataProvider.COL_ID);


    //BAS: deze tabhost voeg ik toe voor de tabInvites en tabStats
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    //BAS: dit hoort nog bij tabhost
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Stats");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabInvites);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Stats");  
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Chat");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabStats); 
    tabSpec.setIndicator("Chat");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);



    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, profileId), null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        profileName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_NAME));
        profileEmail = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL));   
        actionBar.setTitle(profileName);
    }
    actionBar.setSubtitle("connecting ...");

    registerReceiver(registrationStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(Common.ACTION_REGISTER));
    gcmUtil = new GcmUtil(getApplicationContext());

    //BAS: hier zet ik de '+add invite' listener
        buttonNewInvite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddInvite.class);
                intent.putExtra(Common.PROFILE_ID, String.valueOf(profileId));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
    return true;
}   

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.msgInvite_edit: //action_edit CHANGE 
        EditContactDialog dialog = new EditContactDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(Common.PROFILE_ID, profileId);
        args.putString(DataProvider.COL_NAME, profileName);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "EditContactDialog");
        return true;

    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;            
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        //BAS: dit is voor de terugstuur knop in de STATS!
        // BAS: Dit is wanneer de send knop van het Addinvite scherm gebruikt wordt!
    case R.id.buttonSendInvite: 
        send(msgInvite_edit.getText().toString(),null);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        msgInvite_edit.setText(null); }
}
@Override
public void onEditContact(String name) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(name);
}   


//public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  //  Toast.makeText(this,"onListItemClick position is" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //showDetails(position);
//}

public void onYESClick(View v) {        
    int intID = v.getId(); 
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
            Button buttonYES = (Button) findViewById(intID); 
            //Toast.makeText(this, profileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //send(null, profileName);
            //bas:sets to button to 0 everytime you reload it.


            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_BUTTONS, null, null, null, null, null);                          
            if( c != null && c.moveToFirst()){       
                //c.getPosition();
                ans1 = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_ANSCOUNT));
                //System.out.println(ans1); 
                if(ans1 < 0){
                    ans1=0;
                }

                if (ans1 == 0){
                    id = c.getInt(0);
                    buttonYES.setPressed(true);
                     ans1++;
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);

                        values.put(DataProvider.COL_BTNTXT, buttonYES.getHint().toString());
                        values.put(DataProvider.COL_ANSFROM, profileName);
                        values.put(DataProvider.COL_ANSCOUNT, ans1);

                        this.getContentResolver().update(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_BUTTONS, values, "_id = " + id, null);
                 }

                else {
                    id = c.getInt(0);
                    buttonYES.setPressed(false);
                    ans1--; 
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);

                        values.put(DataProvider.COL_BTNTXT, buttonYES.getHint().toString());
                        values.put(DataProvider.COL_ANSFROM, profileName);
                        values.put(DataProvider.COL_ANSCOUNT, ans1);

                        this.getContentResolver().update(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_BUTTONS, values, "_id = " + id, null);
                        //}c.moveToNext();
                    }
                }c.close();
            }
        }


@Override
public String getProfileEmail() {
    return profileEmail;
}

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(msg)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);        
}   


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
    values.put(DataProvider.COL_COUNT, 0);
    getContentResolver().update(Uri.withAppendedPath(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, profileId), values, null, null);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(registrationStatusReceiver);
    gcmUtil.cleanup();
    super.onDestroy();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private BroadcastReceiver registrationStatusReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && Common.ACTION_REGISTER.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            switch (intent.getIntExtra(Common.EXTRA_STATUS, 100)) {
            case Common.STATUS_SUCCESS:
                getActionBar().setSubtitle("online");
                    sendBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    break;

                case Common.STATUS_FAILED:
                    getActionBar().setSubtitle("offline");                  
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        }
    };  

}
```

But at this moment the cursor only takes the position that I give him with c.moveToFirst() in this case. I want this cursor to adapt to the button position it is clicked on. So for example if I click on the top YES button I want it to have affect on that item so it will need to move to the row according to the right column_id. From all that I have read this seems something I need to implement in the fragment but my onItemClick and Listeners have not been any help so far.

It looks a lot like this: [How to Handle Button Clicks ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487253/how-to-handle-button-clicks-listfragment)
but i cant get it to work... how do I set a position for every textballoon implemented by the cursoradapter?

```android
public class StatFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, OnItemClickListener {


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    now = new Date();   


    //BAS: de TABLE_URI die gebruikt wordt voor de adapter staat onderaan deze pagina!! 
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
            R.layout.list_invite, 
            null, 
            new String[]{DataProvider.COL_QUESTION, DataProvider.COL_ANSFROM, DataProvider.COL_ANSCOUNT}, 
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3},
            0);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {                
            //BAS: goed om te weten, de viewbinder is dus degene die daadwerkelijk de string vult met 
            //de waarde die het vertegenwoordigt.LOL

            //BAS: dit is het stukje waar de simplecursoradapter gebruikt wordt om het berichtje 
            // op te halen uit de database, namelijk COL_MSG/COL_AT en deze een id mee te geven, text1 en text2 en 
            // te plaatsen in het messagefragment

            switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.text1:                    
                LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
                //BAS: col_from means it is send by the other person so it comes 'from' someone
                if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_QUESTION)) == null ) {


                } else {

                }
                break;

            case R.id.text2:  
                TextView tv = (TextView) view; 
                tv.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex)); 

                break;

            case R.id.text3: 
                TextView tv3 = (TextView) view; 
                tv3.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex)); 

                break;

            //return true;  
            }
            return false;
            }       

        });     

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //BAS: geen listview aanroepen!! werkt niet goed ofzo..

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setDivider(null); 

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL, mListener.getProfileEmail());
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);

}

private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonYES.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        buttonYES.setTag(1);
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button1 :
            // btn clicked
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity()," Button1 clicked at positon"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        //case R.id.button_id2 :
            // btn2 clicked   
          //         Toast.makeText(context," Button2 clicked at positon"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         //   break;  
       // case R.id.button_id3 :
          //          Toast.makeText(context," Button3 clicked at positon"+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            // btn 3 clciked
          //  break; 
        }

    }
};

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public String getProfileEmail();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String getDisplayTime(String datetime) {
    try {
        Date dt = sdf.parse(datetime);
        if (now.getYear()==dt.getYear() && now.getMonth()==dt.getMonth() && now.getDate()==dt.getDate()) {
            return df[1].format(dt);
        }
        return df[0].format(dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return datetime;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String profileEmail = args.getString(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL);
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
            DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_BUTTONS, 
            null, 
            DataProvider.COL_QFROM + " = ? or " + DataProvider.COL_QTO + " = ?",
            new String[]{profileEmail, profileEmail}, 
            DataProvider.COL_AT + " DESC"); 
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the position of the clicked item you can override the following method in the class extended from **ListFragment**:

```
 onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

position would correspond to the position of the clicked element.